# .NET Core Set ClaimsPrincipal from another controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

In few places in legacy code (more than 100 controllers), we are running action from other controllers.

In .NET Framework it runs OK - `ClaimsPrincipal` in both controller's action have correct values, but in .NET Core, running `SecondController.internalPut()` from `FirstController` gives me `NullReferenceException`.

FirstController:

```
[EnableCors]
public class FirstController : BaseApiController
{
    public FirstController(IContextFactory contextFactory) : base(contextFactory)
    {
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/api/firstcontroller")]
    public IActionResult Put([FromBody] MyDTO data)
    {
        var token = Identity.Token; // <--- correct value

        var secondController = new SecondController(ContextFactory);
        secondController.internalPut(something); <--- NullReferenceException

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

SecondController:

```
[EnableCors]
public class SecondController : BaseApiController
{
    public SecondController(IContextFactory contextFactory) : base(contextFactory)
    {
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put(Guid myGuid)
    {
        internalPut(something); // <-- OK
        return Ok();
    }

    internal void internalPut(object something)
    {
        var token = Identity.Token; // <--- NullReferenceException when running from FirstController!!
    }
}
```

And `BaseApiController` with `TokenIdentity`:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("/api/[controller]")]
[Route("/api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class BaseApiController : ControllerBase
{
    protected readonly IMyContextFactory ContextFactory;

    public BaseApiController(IMyContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        ContextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public TokenIdentity Identity => User?.Identity as TokenIdentity;
}

public class TokenIdentity : GenericIdentity
{
    public Guid Token { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }

    public TokenIdentity(Guid token) : base(token.ToString())
    {
        Token = token;
    }
}
```

How is the easiest fix for this bug? I know that I can change `BaseApiController` implementation to get `ClaimsPrincipal` from `IHttpContextAccessor`, but this means that I need to update constructors for all > 100 controllers in code...
It is another way to always have `ClaimsPrincipal` when we are calling action from another controller?

Comment: When controller object is created by the HTTP pipeline and MVC Framework, it does many other thing with it apart from just calling its constructor. Those things enable us to access HttpContext, Identity, session, route parameters, URL etc. inside the controller. When you are creating controller object using `new`, you are bypassing all that logic. That's why you don't have `Identity` available in your controller object. You are creating controller object and calling method on it as if you are doing unit testing on it. In real application it is never done this way and should not be done.

Comment: You should move the common logic which is needed by FirstController and SecondController to some other class (e.g. Service) and use it in controllers and call method from there...

Comment: It's the `IControllerFactoryProvider` service that builds controller factories. I think it's all the registered `IControllerPropertyActivator` services that are the problem here, as you haven't called the delegates they would create. But this is an implementation detail, which you shouldn't be messing with. Which is why you should never create a controller yourself. Echoing everyone else, if you're going to fix anything, just refactor the common code.

Answer (score 0):

## What I recommend as the correct solution

I can't emphasise enough how much I recommend moving shared functionality into its own services, or perhaps look at using the Mediator Pattern (e.g. using the MediatR library) to decouple your controllers from their functionality a little. What I provide below is not a solution, but a band-aid.

## What I recommend a QUICK FIX only

Why is this only a quick fix?: because this doesn't instantiate the correct action details and route parameters, so it could potentially cause you some hard-to-find bugs, weird behaviour, URLs maybe not generating correctly (if you use this), etc.

Why am I recommending it?: because I know that sometimes time is not on our side and that perhaps you need a quick fix to get this working while you work on a better solution.

### Hacky quick fix

You could add the following method to your base controller class:

```cs
private TController CreateController<TController>() where TController: ControllerBase
{
    var actionDescriptor = new ControllerActionDescriptor()
    {
        ControllerTypeInfo = typeof(TController).GetTypeInfo()
    };

    var controllerFactory = this.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IControllerFactoryProvider>().CreateControllerFactory(actionDescriptor);
    return controllerFactory(this.ControllerContext) as TController;
}
```

Then instead of `var secondController = new SecondController(ContextFactory);` you would write:

```cs
var secondController = CreateController<SecondController>();
```